# Unexpected result from std::wstring::resize_and_overwrite

Tags: c++

this program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::wstring ws;
    for(unsigned i=1;i<64;++i){
        std::cout<<i<<' ';
        ws.resize_and_overwrite(i,[](wchar_t*s,size_t c){std::cout<<c<<'\n';return 0;});
    }

    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
8 14
9 9
10 10
11 11
12 12
13 13
14 14
15 28
16 16
17 17
18 18
19 19
20 20
21 21
22 22
23 23
24 24
25 25
26 26
27 27
28 28
29 56
30 30
31 31
32 32
33 33
34 34
35 35
36 36
37 37
38 38
39 39
40 40
41 41
42 42
43 43
44 44
45 45
46 46
47 47
48 48
49 49
50 50
51 51
52 52
53 53
54 54
55 55
56 56
57 112
58 58
59 59
60 60
61 61
62 62
63 63
```

However, according to the doc https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/resize_and_overwrite,
`2. Evaluates std::move(op)(p, count).`

the values of i and c should always be the same. What is wrong with the code, did I miss something? I guess there must be some undefined behavior at work. The output in https://godbolt.org/ is not the same as that of my PC, but i and c are still different in some iterations.

Comment: Reproducible with libstdc++ on both GCC and Clang regardless of optimization flags: https://godbolt.org/z/v5oh3szqY

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your program has well-defined behavior and should always produce equal values on each line according to the current C++23 draft.

The behavior you see is due to libstdc++ being non-conforming to the current C++23 draft. A bug report for this already exists [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104222).

As stated in the bug report, the intention (which seems reasonable to me) might have been that the user-callable is (at least sometimes) given information about the actual size of the allocation that way, so that it can potentially use that extra space that is already allocated. However, this is not conforming to the standard draft. I don't know whether Jonathan Wakely intents to make libstdc++ conforming or instead to propose adapting the standard. I didn't find any matching open LWG issue at https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-index.html.

Comment: Contrary to Janathan Wakely's claim, the user-callable isn't usually given the actual capacity. It's only given the actual capacity when the capacity is increased, and even then only if it's increased up to twice the original capacity.

Comment: It is weird. Before posting I looked at gcc's implementation `resize_and_overwrite(size_type __n, _Operation __op)` in `include\c++\12.2.0\bits\basic_string.tcc`. I couldn't find anywhere that __n is modified.

Comment: @interjay If it was intentional (Jonathan Wakely didn't seem entirely sure in the comment either), then it is applied inconsistently, I agree.

Comment: @user42471 The call to `_M_create` takes `__n` by-reference and (potentially) modifies it on reallocation. That it isn't possible to distinguish pass-by-reference from pass-by-value at the call site is one of C++'s big problems.